# Ошибка в AngularJS

Tags: ajax, angularjs, scope

Выводится ошибка в AngularJS

> AngularJS controller cant get value from $rootScope

Вот сам код:

```
//инициализирую $rootScope.data
define(['angular'], function (ng) {
'use strict';
return ng.module('app.controllers', ['ngRoute'])
    .run(function($rootScope, $http) {
        $http.get('/tabs/tabs.json')
            .success(function(data) {
                $rootScope.data = data;
            });
    });
});

define(['./module'], function (controllers) {
'use strict';
controllers.controller('tabsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
    //не могу получить доступ к свойствам $scope - undefined
    $scope.tabId = $routeParams.id;

    if($scope.tabId) {
        for(var item in $scope.data) {
            if(item.id === $scope.tabId) {
                $scope.activeTab = item;
                $scope.path = item.path;
            }
        };
    } else {
        for(var item in $scope.data) {
            if(item.order === 0) {
                $scope.activeTab = item;
            }
        };
    }

    $scope.changeActiveTab = function(tab) {
        $scope.activeTab = tab;
        $scope.path = tab.path;
    };
}]);
});
```

В чём может быть причина?

Comment: Вы записываете данные в $rootScope, а хотите получить эти данные из $scope?

Comment: $scope прототипно наследуется от $rootScope, по этому можно получить доступ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас данные грузятся при старте приложения, а используете вы их в каком то контроллере.

Вы начинаете использовать данные не дожидаясь их загрузки.
После того как загрузите данные нужно послать `$digest` событие для всех дочерних `scope`

```js
$http.get('/tabs/tabs.json')
  .success(function(data) {
    $rootScope.data = data;
    $rootScope.$digest()
  });
```

А в контроллере нужно подписаться на событие изменения этих данных

```js
$scope.$watch("data",function(newVal, oldVal, scope){
 /// тут выполняете необходимые действия над данными
 /// только не забывайте проверять значения на undefined
}
```